# Exception in Application start method how to read error output

Tags: java, javafx

im fairly new to coding and need to learn JavaFX and Java in 3 Weeks for school.
I need to learn to read those error files, because 3 weeks is not long and i cant ask everytime in this forum xd.
So maybe someone can teach me/send me an documentation or something to reading and understanding the errors in the output.
Im using Intellij and im getting this error code:

> Exception in Application start method
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
> at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
> java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
> method    at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
> at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or
> resource not found    at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1135)
> at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/javafx.scene.image.Image.(Image.java:625)
> at
> com.example.speedreading.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:15)
> at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
> at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
> at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
> at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
> at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
> at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
> Method)   at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
> ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL
> or resource not found     at
> javafx.graphics@18.0.1/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1120)
> ... 11 more Exception running application
> com.example.speedreading.HelloApplication
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.speedreading;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        Image icon = new Image("mb.png");
        stage.getIcons().add(icon);
        stage.setTitle("SpeedReading");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

This all happened, when i finally got everything set up and all errors fixed, and tried to set a picture as a icon of my window.
I have no clue what the error means and cant read/understand it.

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: So the key part is "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found ... at com.example.speedreading.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:15)". And the specific problem is described in detail at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other